# Gstreamer: capturing still frames from webcam with appsink?

Tags: c, linux, gstreamer, webcam

I currently have a working C program that streams continuous frames from a webcam to an appsink. However, I'm only interested in capturing single frames when the user presses a key.

In other words: when idle, the appsink receives no frames, but when a key is pressed, the appsink should pull a single new frame from the camera source.

I've tried using an `output_selector` as a "valve" to switch frames between a `fakesink` and my `appsink`. So when the app is idle, the pipeline is running, and looks like

`v4l2src -> output_selector -> fakesink`

and when I want to capture a frame, I change the `output_selector`'s active pad so the pipeline looks like this:

`v4l2src -> output_selector -> jpegenc -> appsink`

Then I do `gst_app_sink_pull_sample()` and switch the active pad back to the `fakesink`. The issue with this is that sometimes (usually every other capture) I get a duplicate frame that's the same as the last one. How can I resolve this issue? Is there another way to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: What is the output from `output_selector`? Is it A: raw decompressed video frames, or B: a compressed video stream.  If it's B then your scheme has very little chance of working.

Comment: The output from `output_selector` is raw frames. The reason I put `output_selector` before `jpegenc` is to avoid encoding frames that just will be discarded.

Comment: If the pipeline starts up sufficiently quickly, you may just want to it on-demand, when the user presses a key, and set the `num-buffers` attribute on v4l2src to one.